# Access: Auto-Fill in values in a table based on certain criteria. (Payment schedule)

Tags: ms-access

I basically want to create a payment schedule in a separate table based on 4 values that a user would select. The payment schedule is very basic and the table only needs 2 columns, 1) Date of payment, 2) payment amount.

The 4 criteria values that are used to fill out this simple table would be: 1) the total amount of money, 2) number of payments, 3) the frequency of the payments (monthly, quarterly, semi-annually, annually), 4) the date of the first payment.

The way that I envision this is having a Form where these 4 values will be selected. On that form there can be a button to execute the command to fill in a datasheet with the appropriate values.

The first entry would obviously be on the date of the first payment, and the amount for that entry would be the total amount divided by the number of payments. For the second record dollar amount would be the same and the date would be the first payment date + the frequency. So if the first payment date is 1/1/2000 and the frequency annually, then the second entry date would be 1/1/2001. Etc.. until the last payment is made.

While it is a pretty simple payment schedule, I'm not sure how to best approach this in Access and if it's even possible. Would appreciate some input and direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will need

-- A numbers table with integers from 0 to the highest number of payments possible, indexed on the number.

-- A combobox called Frequency on forms payments with the following properties:

```
Row source: q;quarter;m;month;ww;week
Row source type : value list
Bound column : 1
Column count : 2
Column widths : 0, 1
```

-- A query

```
INSERT INTO Payments ( UserID, PaymentDate, Payment )
SELECT [Forms]![Payments]![UserID], 
       DateAdd([Forms]![Payments]![Frequency],
       [Number],
       [Forms]![Payments]![Startdate]) AS Expr2, 
       [Forms]![Payments]![LoanAmount]/
                 [Forms]![Payments]![NumberOfPayments] AS Expr3
FROM Numbers
WHERE (((Numbers.Number)<[Forms]![Payments]![NumberOfPayments]));
```

-- A button to run the query.

Comment: This worked great. Really appreciate the detailed steps. Thank you!