# How to Create a table where fields are days of the year in Access 2010?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, datefield

So the question is pretty much all in the title. I was just wondering if there is an easy way to create a table and have a field for each day of the year without doing 365 entries.

The reason I want this is to make it easier for weekly, monthly and year to date (YTD) calculations. Ideally what I would like to have is a set of tables to represent Days of the Year, Months and then a Year table. Each field would be filled automatically immediately following the date they represent.

Example: In the Days Table we see the adjacent field 7/9/2012  and 7/10/2012. Once the internal clock hits 7/10/2012, the 7/9/2012 filed would populate with the data calc'd from other fields.

The same would go for months as well as years.

Comment: Why are you going back to the idea of three tables after you previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11368134/access-2010-date-data-management#comment14978209_11368134 ?

Comment: Some notes on a numbers table : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676637/access-auto-fill-in-values-in-a-table-based-on-certain-criteria-payment-sched/8680368#8680368

Comment: @Remou I'm fine with using the one table, but as I asked, the main question is there an easy way to create such a table in Access? Since I would prefer not to spend the time creating 365+ fields.

Comment: @Remou My situation is a bit more complicated. I'm creating an equipment availability database. So I have a table Representing the equipment, as well as the maintenance period. This new table will track the daily availability to be used for reports. But equipment may go down several times a day, or the maintenance table may have incorrect info. This means that the Availability table needs to pull from multiple records and needs to adjust on its own. This is where I'm unsure on how to approach.

Answer (score 3):

*I was just wondering if there is an easy way to create a table and have a field for each day of the year without doing 365 entries.*

Despite the fact that I'm uncertain about exactly what you have in mind, I am fairly certain the correct answer is "No, there is no easy way". :-)

Creating an Access table with 365 fields (what about leap years?!) is beyond not easy.  It's impossible because the maximum number of fields in an Access table is 255.

If you were willing to settle for a portion of a year which fits within that limit, a table with a column for each date still seems like a monumentally bad idea to me.

OTOH, a calendar table with one row per date ("*columns are expensive; rows are cheap*") can be very useful.  I don't understand why you've apparently rejected that approach.

The size of the table shouldn't be a big concern: <= 366 rows per year, but those can be *narrow* rows.

If the issue is the burden to load all the dates for a given year, that burden can be quite trivial.  Just run this `LoadCalendar` procedure.  Without any parameters, it will load the dates for the current year into a Date/Time field named `the_date` in a table named `tblCalendar`.  You can use the parameters to substitute different year, table, or field.

```
Public Sub LoadCalendar(Optional ByVal pYear As Integer, _
        Optional ByVal pTable As String = "tblCalendar", _
        Optional ByVal pField As String = "the_date")
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim dte As Date
    Dim dteLast As Date
    Dim intYear As Integer
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strMsg As String

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    intYear = IIf(pYear = 0, Year(Date), pYear)
    dte = DateSerial(intYear, 1, 1)
    dteLast = DateSerial(intYear, 12, 31)

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(pTable, dbOpenTable, dbAppendOnly)

    Do While dte <= dteLast
        rs.AddNew
        rs.Fields(pField).value = dte
        rs.Update
        dte = dte + 1
    Loop
    rs.Close

ExitHere:
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    strMsg = "Error " & Err.Number & " (" & Err.Description _
        & ") in procedure LoadCalendar"
    MsgBox strMsg
    GoTo ExitHere
End Sub
```

If you want to load multiple years in one go, simply do something like this in the Immediate window:

```
for yr = 2000 to 2012 : LoadCalendar yr : next
```

Comment: I posted a link above to an easy way `Some notes on a numbers table` :)

Comment: @Remou Do you actually mean an easy way to "*have a field for each day of the year*"?  I thought OP meant separate fields for each date: fld_20120709; fld_s0120710; etc.  That seems horrific to me.

Comment: Wow! I did not read that right, my mind must have skittered away from the whole idea of anything other than a *row* for each day!

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you start in excel, click and drag the date range and columns you want, and then import/establish a connection between excel an your database? Quick, simple, no coding required. I believe you could link to the excel sheet and use date functions in the excel sheet to have this update automatically upon connection refresh although I haven't tried linking.

P.S. I am by no means an expert, please let me know if there is a better practice.